# coloring patches with specific in a domain

Tags: netlogo

I want to have pcolor of my outer-ring patches as green
I have written following command

```
    To setup
    ask patch 0 0 [ set pcolor red
                 ask neighbors
                    [ set pcolor blue]
    ask patches with [pxcor > 1 and pxcor < -1 and pycor > 1 and pycor < -1] 
    [set pcolor green ]
      ]

   end
```

I get center and neighbors with required color but out ring of patches remained black.

plz help.

Comment: These are two very different questions.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: So I need to post 1 question at a time. Is this question editable? I will be posting in a while.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you provide a condition that no patch can satisfy.  (E.g., it cannot be both to the left of your colored patches and to the right, but you use `and`.)  Does the following meet your needs?

```
to colorPatches
  ask patch 0 0 [
    set pcolor red
    ask neighbors [ set pcolor blue]
  ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = black] [ 
    set pcolor green
  ]
end
```

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much for the help.